# How can I uninstall old Nvidia drivers from DriverStore FileRepository?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-geforce, geforce-experience

I recently noticed that Nvidia uses a lot of space on my main drive.

It looks like files from previous installations weren't removed. I tried to download the latest version and install it with "clean installation" checked. It freed a few gigabytes but most of the files are still there.

I also tried to uninstall all the Nvidia softwares from the Control Panel and do a clean install next but nothing changed.

Right now I still have :

- 11.3GB in *C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation*
- 38 folders of 300-400MB in *C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository*

Is there a way to remove old NVIDIA drivers, to save disk space or to prepare for a clean install?

Comment: use DDU to remove the driver: http://www.wagnardmobile.com/?q=display-driver-uninstaller-ddu-

Comment: It worked, thank you. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called [Display Driver Uninstaller - DDU](http://www.wagnardmobile.com/?q=display-driver-uninstaller-ddu-) which removes really all files that each Driver installation puts on the HDD when the official uninstaller still leaves files left or the offical uninstallers fail:

> Display Driver Uninstaller is a **driver removal utility** that can help
>   you **completely remove AMD/NVIDIA/Intel graphics card drivers** and
>   packages from your system, **without leaving leftovers behind (including
>   registry keys, folders and files, and the driver store)**.
>
> The AMD/NVIDIA/Intel video drivers can normally be uninstalled from
>   the Windows Control panel, this driver uninstaller program was
>   designed to be used in cases where the standard driver uninstall
>   fails, or whenever you need to thoroughly delete Intel, nVidia or
>   ATI/AMD video card drivers.  The current effect after you use this
>   driver removal will be similar as if its the first time you install a
>   new driver just like a fresh, clean install of Windows. As with any
>   tool of this kind, we recommend creating a new system restore point
>   before using it, so that you can revert your system at any time if you
>   run into problems.

Answer (score 4):

Another method is to use [Driver Store Explorer (RAPR)](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer). (Note - I have no affiliation with this product).  This lists the drivers and lets you select ones to remove.

I didn't try this personally, but I read on other sites that if you try to remove a driver that is in use it will fail, so there is not really any risk here of accidentally uninstalling drivers that are not old.

[image: RAPR screenshot]

Don't ask me why there are 30 copies of the same driver version with the same date taking up 15 GB of space, but I removed them all (just leaving the latest one) and didn't encounter any problems.